# Cambiar el origen de una tabla dinámica a la active sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macros, tabla-dinámica

Es bastante sencillo lo que quiero hacer, no sé cómo solucionar la última parte para poder cambiar el origen de mi tabla dinamica a la hoja actual.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim Hoja As String

Hoja = ActiveSheet.Name

With ActiveSheet
    .PivotTables("TablaDinámica1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
        PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:="'" & .Hoja & "'!TablaDinámica1")
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería funcionarte, siempre y cuando `TablaDinámica1` sea un nombre de un rango:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()

    Dim Hoja As Worksheet 'utiliza variables de objeto hoja

    Set Hoja = ActiveSheet 'aunque no te recomiendo utilizar esto
    'te recomiendo utilizar por ejemplo ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MiHoja")

    With Hoja
        .PivotTables("TablaDinámica1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
            PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'" & .Name & "'!TablaDinámica1")
    End With

    'si TablaDinámica1  no es un nombre de rango te recomiendo hacer esto:
    Dim MiRango As Range
    With Hoja
        Set MiRango = .Range("A1:C100") 'aquí pon tu rango
        .PivotTables("TablaDinámica1").ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook. _
            PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'" & .Name & "'!" & MiRango.Address)
    End With

End Sub
```